# Difference of two uniforms from first principles

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

Let $U \sim U(0,1)$ and $V\sim U(0,1)$  be two independent uniform random variables. Find the pdf of $U=X-Y$.

My attempt:
First find the CDF of U.
$$P(U\leq t) = P(X-Y \leq t) = \int_0^1 P(X\leq t+y) F_Y(y) = \int_0^1 F_X(t+y)F_Y(y)$$
Evaluating this integral, I get $F_U(t) = \frac{t}{2}+1/3$.
To find the pdf, I differentiate this to obtain $f_U(t) = 1/2$ which I know is wrong but I have no idea where I went wrong.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: use a geometric sketch : it will be quite evident !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slow solution: first, find pdf of $Z=-Y$, which is quite straightforward in two steps: first, find CDF $F_{Z}(z) = P(Y\geq -z)$. The inequality changed because $Z=\varphi(Y)$ is a decreasing function, therefore you want $Y\geq \varphi^{-1}(z)$. Once you have got it, differentiate wrt $z$ to get $f_Z(z): Z \sim R[-1,0]$ is Now you have
$$
U=X+Z
$$
It is easier to find pdf of $U$ rather than CDF using convolution formula:
$$
f_{U}(u) = \int f_{Z}(u-x)f_{X}(x)dx
$$
Obvisouly $f_{Z}(u-x)$ is not $0$ only when $-1 <u-x<0$. Therefore you can split the support of the integral into 2 intervals:
$$
\int_{0}^{x<u+1}f_X(x)dx \ \text { if } -1 <u<0\\
\int_{x>u}^{1}f_{X}(x)dx \ \text { if } 0<u<1
$$
Outside of these intervals it is $0$.

Comment: Thanks a ton! How does this expression imply $1-|u|$ for $u \in[-1,1]$?

Comment: Solve both integrals, and you get your expression (or $\{1+u, 1-u\}$) if you wish, which is the same thing

Comment: Great. Accepted the answer. Thanks again.